# setting emulator landscape mode problem

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have developed a project which should run only in landscape mode. I set in manifest file like this android:screenOrientation="landscape". This is working fine in emulator but when i am running in nexus one it is still coming in portrait mode.Any idea any one?

Comment: Does landscape mode work as expected in other applications? It is possible to set the phone to only be in portrait mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I want one of my apps running in landscape mode I add on my onCreate the following line :

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Hope that is what you expect.

Comment: Thanks but I know this but setting manifest file is better and it will put the same impact as in manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

Dunno, AndroidMirza. I tried it on two Nexus One phones, one running Gingerbread and one running Eclair, and it works as expected.  Here's what I did:

1. Create Android project
2. Open AndroidManifest.xml
3. In <activity> tag, add:

   android:screenOrientation="landscape"

In both cases (and AVD with GB), the screen orientation immediately locks to landscape in my Activity. I used [Ctrl] + [Space] to let the IDE auto-complete for me, to make sure there were no typos.

All I can think is, either there is an error in how you are specifying landscape, or something elsewhere in your code or manifest is defeating it.

Comment: Thanks but if there will be any error in manifest file it will run totally. You also know that very well i know. I donot know what is the problem